# Pass value of ng-src to ng-model - AngularJs Signature Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-v1

I have an app with [Angular Signature](https://github.com/legalthings/angular-signature) directive.

This directive allow you draw a sign in a canvas, the content of this canvas is rendered in a `<img>` tag (base64)

```
<div class="container">
    <signature-pad
        accept="accept" clear="clear"
        height="220" width="568"
        dataurl="dataurl">
    </signature-pad>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button ng-click="signature = accept()">Generate</button>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="result" ng-show="signature">
    <img ng-src="{{signature.dataUrl}}" />
</div>
```

The image base64 is in `{{signature.dataUrl}}` , The image base64 it is generated very fine.

[image]

I want to pass value of ng-src to ng-model. I tried to do this.

```
<div class="result" ng-show="signature">
    My ng-model (in my controller)  : {{mySign}}
    <img ng-model="mySign" ng-src="{{signature.dataUrl}}" class="imagen-firma" />
</div>
```

In my controller I have initialized:

```
$scope.mySign = "";
```

But the value of ng-src (base64) not pass to my ng-model.
How can I do that?

Comment: `ng-model="signature.dataUrl"`?

Comment: But ng-model="signature.dataUrl" is not in my controller, ng-model="signature.dataUrl" is part of Directive

Comment: if `signature.dataUrl` is populated dynamically, then do it within the function (I'm guessing) `accept()`. e.g. `$scope.mySign = $scope.signature.dataUrl`

Comment: But @AlekseySolovey, **$scope.signature.dataUrl** is not in my controller, **signature.dataUrl** came from directive, can you explain me how can do to signature.dataUrl work in my controller please.

Comment: @ELM I'm not familiar with directive-to-controller communications, I think you need to bind controller's variable through directive's scope. Alternatively, you might want to use a service, just like in a controller-to-controller communication

Comment: @ELM Have you ever got answer to this issue? I am facing the same issue while using this directive.

Answer (score -1):

img tag haven't support ng-model directive use ng-init directive for binding.

```
<div class="result" ng-show="signature">
    My ng-model (in my controller)  : {{mySign}}
    <img ng-src="{{signature.dataUrl}}" ng-init="mySign = " class="imagen-firma" />
</div>
```

Comment: I believe `ng-init` fires when the controller is loaded, but `signature` is generated dynamically from a function, so it will always be undefined